# How to increase formula by increment of 10

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet with one value per year. I would like to take the average of decades (with, obviously, 10 cells per decade), so I set up a formula along the lines of `=AVERAGE(A(1+10):(A(10+10)`, hoping to be able to drag it so each cell would populate with A11:A20, A21:30, and so on. How do I do this? I'm not particularly savvy with the formulae in Google Sheets.

Comment: @user0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jwK7mlUtg_oNQcRORHsG6ReTDtFGChHlXZxSSacJXMU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

- cell **O2**: **`=AVERAGE(N1:N10)`**
- cell **O3** and drag down: **`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("N"&1+(ROW(A1)&0)&":N"&10+(ROW(A1)&0)))`**

  [image: 0]